# Do I need to escape strings on Symfony2 with Doctrine queries?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've this code:
I get some data from a GET request:

```
$username = $request->get('username');
```

And then, I use doctrine to check if this username exists or not:

```
$found = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Users')->findByNick($username);
            if ($found){
               //nickname in use
            } else {
               //not found
            }
```

As you can see, I've no String escaping, so the value is directly sent to Doctrine. Is this a security issue? Should it be slashed for security reasons?
Note that I never use RAW queries, just prebuild ones from Doctrine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to do it with prepared statements.

You can read here:http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/security.html

And I've tried it out. This is the query generated by Doctrine:

> WHERE t0.nick = 'dasdfaf\\' OR 1'

As you can see, several slashes were added.

Comment: Yep.  No need to worry about it in doctrine.  But it's usually called "escaping"